# Navbar completely messed up using React-Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

My navbar is all over the place, I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong. 
I just started using react-bootstrap, but I'm pretty sure I am importing everything correctly.

Here is what my navbar looks like: 
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown, NavItem, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
              Link
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
              Link
            </NavItem>
            <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem divider />
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
          <Nav pullRight>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
              Link Right
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
              Link Right
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if your css has been imported, are you using webpack?

Comment: I accidentally had v4 imported instead of v3. While this is not the "direct" answer it fixed my problem. I am using webpack, how should I do this with webpack ?

Comment: try install a css-loader in dev dependencies